# A .deploy file is not deploying an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, clickonce, deployment

I'm developing an application using MS [Visual C# 2008 Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express) that uses the ClickOnce deployment functionality. I publish the application to a a server where users can download it.

Upon running the application, it throws a file not found exception - it cannot find the XML file that the application pulls data from (`Instructions.xml`).

When I go to the server and into the Application Files folder, I see .deploy files. One of them is for `Instructions.xml.deploy`.

Why is `Instructions.xml` not being included in the user's download?

Of course, if I manually copy `Instructions.xml` to my personal copy of the program, the program works fine. But the publishing process is supposed to (via `Instructions.xml.deploy`?) copy / deploy this file automatically.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The XML file is probably in the ClickOnce data directory (XML files are automatically marked as data files).

Read *[Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx)* (MSDN). It explains how data files are used and accessed using ClickOnce. If you want to publish the XML file as an application file (you want it published to the same directory as the application), follow the steps below:

1. Go into your Project's properties
2. Go to the publish tab.
3. Click "Application Files"
4. Find your XML file in the list and change the "Publish Status" of your file to "Include".
5. Change "Download Group" to "Required".

If you want to use it as a data file, there is an example in the mentioned article.

Comment: In my case there was no .xml file listed.  I simply added a good copy of my .xml file to the project and it appeared on the "Application Files" page.

Comment: In case someone is looking for how to find that XML file in the code after you've done this, it should be found at this path 

`string xmlFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + xmlFile;`
`xdc.load(xmlFilePath);`

In some cases, it might be available in a subdirectory called 'Resources' of the above BaseDirectory so the xmlFilePath would change accordingly.