# I have issues with publishing my WInForms app with 3rd party CLIs. How do I avoid the "The specified module could not be found" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, command-line-interface, publish

I'm new to C# and programming outside Matlab in general, and have spent a long time looking into this issue.

My program uses several 3rd party CLIs and also some native C DLLs, all for x64. They are all in the correct folder and referenced, and the build target platform for my program is also set for x64. Target framework is .NET 4.7.2. in VS2022. The program works fine in both debug and release mode IF I choose "Any CPU" next to the debug/release dropdown. (This confuses me and might be the source of the error. Could you please help me understand the difference between build target platform and debug/release target platform, and why does one have to be x64 and the other "Any CPU"? - it doesn't compile if I set it otherwise, ie. both to x64.)

When I was debugging, I found that one of the CLIs can't load if a DLL called "PrivateInternal" from the SDK is not in the folder. So I put it in the folder, however I can't reference it and I dont know what it does. The program works fine inside VS as long as "PrivateInternal" is in the folder.

My problem is: When I publish the app, I can install it and everything. But when I press a button that initiates code with the mentioned CLI above, it returns the "The specified module could not be found" exception.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI.dll' or one of its
> dependencies. The specified module could not be found. File name:
> 'Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI.dll'    at
> StageControlUI.Form1.GetSerialNumbers()    at
> StageControlUI.Form1.btn_connect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)...

I suspect its due to the "PrivateInternal" DLL not being referenced , but it could also be because Im somehow publishing it wrong. I have looked into publishing issues and considerations for WinForms and CLIs (for example [Debugging Assembly Loading Failures](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212004447/http:/blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx)).
But I would like some guidance on how to proceed from my current standpoint?

Comment: That is a lot of guesses, none of them correct, and not enough facts.  Focus on what you do know, name the specific product and DLLs that you use so somebody has a shot at telling you how to configure the project and what DLL you forgot to publish.  Talking to the manufacturer's support channels is otherwise by far the best way to resolve the issues.

Comment: When you change compiler options you have to do a clean build.

Comment: @Hans, I tried to add as much fact as I could but yes, I own that they are also guesses. Being new in C# and after spending days of reading suggestions and still not even understand if they are relevant to my issue, how can I claim that anything I know is a fact?  "Forgot to publish" - Are you saying the DLLs needs to be published separately? Yes, the DLLs are all included in the published build EXCEPT the one I mention I have issues with, and I have descriped all the information regarding that. I have contacted the manufacturer, they did not know what PrivateInternal does.

Answer (score -1):

With AnyCPU/x64 you are talking about the target platform your application should be running on. If you build your project on AnyCPU for example you want your application to run on any device regardless of the architecture of the CPU.

**My guess why your module is not found is that you didnt choose the right build platform in the configuration manager for your project!**

To open the configuration manager: right click on solution -> Configuration Manager...

Here you need to select the decired building mode and the platform you want to build. Now check if all Project have the right mapping. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the same exception even in debug/build mode if I change the configuration manager settings to x64.

Comment: If possible add the Exception to your question.

Comment: I have added the exception to the question. 
Since the entire program including all the CLIs works as intended in VS, I don't see why it should not work in a published form, this is the aspect I dont understand. Sorry if the whole backstory is confusing, I tried to add as much information as possible.

Comment: Check if the dll named "Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI.dll" is in the root folder of your application in time of execution

Comment: It is indeed in the folder, except Once published, it is called "Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI.dll.deploy". This happens to all the CLIs and some of the DLLs.

Comment: Hmm I´m guessing that there is something wrong with the publishing.. have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955958/how-to-deploy-a-c-sharp-application-while-including-third-party-dll-files

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a step in the right direction. Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI is dependent on a native C DLL which seems to not be installed although it is in the folder., since it keeps the .deploy after the installation process. This lead me to find that unmanaged DLLs are not allowed in oneClick publishing and I might need a workaround with packaging. Im looking further into this